# Drupal as a Proxy

Tags: php, security, drupal, proxy

I have a php web site, and i don't want to expose it directly due to security issues.
Is it possible to make drupal as proxy? to manage the authentication... as if my website is drupal module.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I used to do it this with Drupal module taxonomy_access in order to manage access to content in Drupal.

But I think in your case, it would be much simpler if you just use Apache with some kind of authentification : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html

And if you really want a proxy you could mix it with mod_proxy : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html